# Assets tag pair not outputting anything

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic

I have an Assets field set up with multiple images selected inside a channel entry. When I try to output these images using the code below, nothing appears.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="list_photos" entry_id="37" limit="1" disable="categories|pagination|member_data"}
  {photo}
    <li><a href="{photo:url}" class="gal" rel="group" title="{photo_description}"><img src="/phpthumb/phpThumb.php?src={photo:url}&w=200&h=140&zc=1&q=80" width="200" height="140" /></a></li>
  {/photo}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Can anyone identify the problem?

EE 2.5.5

Assets 2.0.5

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the prefix when you're within the tag pair (the `field_name` prefix is only for when you want to access one of the field's properties outside of the tag pair):

```
{photo}
    <li><a href="{url}" class="gal" rel="group" title="{photo_description}"><img src="/phpthumb/phpThumb.php?src={url}&w=200&h=140&zc=1&q=80" width="200" height="140" /></a></li>
{/photo}
```